# Pandas : add multiple dates to a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code  that imports a employee clockin row and works out the 30 minute intervals that the employee is in the building.  I then want to assign this ("sample_employee_clockin_dates") back to the orignial dataframe but im getting error :

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

```
import pandas as pd


    sample_employee_clockin = pd.DataFrame({'direction_in': {15831: Timestamp('2019-06-25 04:37:59')}, 'emp': {15831: 73.0}, 'direction_out': {15831: Timestamp('2019-06-25 15:17:35')}, 'time_difference': {15831: '0 days 10:39:36'}, 'complete_record': {15831: 'yes'}, 'terminal': {15831: 1.0}, 'job_title': {15831: 44.0}, 'division': {15831: 1.0}})

    for label, row in sample_employee_clockin.iterrows():
        date_in = row["direction_in"]
        date_out = row["direction_out"]
        sample_employee_clockin_dates = pd.date_range(start=date_in.floor(freq="30min"),end=date_out.ceil(freq="30min"),freq='30min')

    sample_employee_clockin["clock_in_times"] = sample_employee_clockin_dates
```

The full error is :

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-81-59a967c4631c> in <module>
>       8     sample_employee_clockin_date = pd.date_range(start=date_in.floor(freq="30min"),end=date_out.ceil(freq="30min"),freq='30min')
>       9 
> ---> 10 sample_employee_clockin["clock_in_times"] = sample_employee_clockin_date
>
> c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> ```
>
> **setitem**(self, key, value)
>          3117         else:
>          3118             # set column
>       -> 3119             self._set_item(key, value)
>          3120 
>          3121     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):
>
> ```
> c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> ```
>
> _set_item(self, key, value)
>          3192 
>          3193         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
>       -> 3194         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
>          3195         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
>          3196
>
> ```
> c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> ```
>
> _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
>          3389 
>          3390             # turn me into an ndarray
>       -> 3391             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
>          3392             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
>          3393                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:
>
> ```
> c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
> ```
>
> _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
>          3999 
>          4000     if len(data) != len(index):
>       -> 4001         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
>          4002 
>          4003     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:
>
> ```
> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
> ```

Comment: You try to add a new column with 23 rows to a one-row-dataframe

Comment: is it not possible to add multiple values to a column in a one-row-dataframe?  I'm sure ive seen examples of adding datafreames to existing dataframes or something simular.  Not sure on the best way to do this.  Maybe there is another way to do this that meets my needs?#

Comment: maybe you can try to put a list into the cell like:  `sample_employee_clockin.at[15831,'clock_in_times'] = sample_employee_clockin_dates.to_list()`

Comment: ran the line but its tolist() instead of to_list().  it came back with "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Comment: put `sample_employee_clockin["clock_in_times"] = pd.Series` in front of it, so it should work

Comment: Could you write the full line out.  I'm not understanding the aim...

Comment: `sample_employee_clockin["clock_in_times"] = pd.Series
sample_employee_clockin.at[15831,'clock_in_times'] = sample_employee_clockin_dates.to_list()
`

Comment: did it work as you wanted it?

Comment: no, it may be the way its formatted but i get error **SyntaxError: invalid syntax** .  it was 3 eqaul signs in one line which isnt possible is it?

Comment: hi, these are two lines, it's impossible to post it properly into stack overflow's comments

Comment: can you write it a answer, that way it will be easier to see :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it isn't possible to add multiline code-comments here the code:

```
import pandas as pd


sample_employee_clockin = pd.DataFrame({'direction_in': {15831: pd.Timestamp('2019-06-25 04:37:59')}, 'emp': {15831: 73.0}, 'direction_out': {15831: pd.Timestamp('2019-06-25 15:17:35')}, 'time_difference': {15831: '0 days 10:39:36'}, 'complete_record': {15831: 'yes'}, 'terminal': {15831: 1.0}, 'job_title': {15831: 44.0}, 'division': {15831: 1.0}})

for label, row in sample_employee_clockin.iterrows():
    date_in = row["direction_in"]
    date_out = row["direction_out"]
    sample_employee_clockin_dates = pd.date_range(start=date_in.floor(freq="30min"),end=date_out.ceil(freq="30min"),freq='30min')

sample_employee_clockin["clock_in_times"] = pd.Series
sample_employee_clockin.at[15831,'clock_in_times'] = sample_employee_clockin_dates.to_list()
```

Comment: perfect, just the answer i was looking for.